# In Laravel 5.4 ,Is it possible to include a specific CSS file for a certain blade template?

Tags: css, laravel

I have tried the following in my blade template:

```
@section('styles')
<link href="{{asset('assets/css/app.css')}}" />
@stop
```

In the master blade template I have included the following:

```
<link href=asset('/assets/template/css//invoiceTemplate.css')rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I you want to include a CSS / JS file for a specific blade use stacks ([see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#stacks))

from the documentation:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

You may push to a stack as many times as needed. To render the complete stack contents, pass the name of the stack to the @stack directive:

```
<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->

    @stack('scripts')
</head>
```

you can also place them at the bottom of your blade (where a lot of people call thier JS files these days)

Comment: I have tried this,but its not working.On the other hand the documentation was written for specifying any JavaScript libraries. I want to add css file

Comment: MMm peculiar.. i use this for everything (CSS/JS) on specific blades - what specifically is not working, no link? or is the correct generation of your link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@yield('styles')` to your master blade template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Write this code to your master template

```
@yield('page-styles')
```

and add this also to the specific blade file where you want to add a specific CSS file.

```
@section('page-styles')
    //Your specific css file
@stop
```

Make sure that the parameter inside the `@section` and `@yield` are the same.
In this case, I've used `'page-styles'`.